# Simple multilingual CMS?

Tags: php, python, ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, multilingual

I have been searching for a while now for a dead simple CMS with multi-language support. The ideal candidate is very lean and offers the possibility to set up different languages for different domains. It's OK if the language support is provided by a plugin/extension.

For example I want example.com to point to English and example.fr should be French. With different URI-mappings for SEO.

It can be developed in either of PHP, Ruby or Python and has to be open source.

Any tips?
Thank you

**EDIT / MORE DETAILS**
What I want is a CMS that is as simple to use and grasp for a client as Radiant is, but with tabs on each resource that can translate articles to different languages.

Languages have to be able to use multiple domains, one for each language.

I want to easily use the same article for more than one language as well as have articles (e.g. blog posts or news stories) that are only connected to one language.

The CMS should be very light in core functionality (like Radiant, unlike Drupal/Joomla) but be easily extendable with plugins.

Comment: Your described requirements aren't specific enough to recommend anything, really. Can you elaborate a lot more so you might get more concrete answers than just Typo3 / Django-CMS / Joomla / etc.etc. because pretty much every CMS has the features you have described so far.

Comment: Take a look at zenar.io CMS its alive project very good in my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

My requirements (or let's say the requirements of clients): PHP, MySQL, shared hosting.

After a long research and testing period I finally found [Processwire CMS](http://processwire.com/). Using their [tutorial over here](https://processwire.com/api/multi-language-support/multi-language-fields/) I got the multilingual feature running in a couple of minutes. Just install the modules for "Languages Support" and "Multi-Language". Then you can define languages under Setup > Languages. Afterwards when editing or creating a page, the defined languages will appear in the page settings. For each language you will find a custom textarea for instance.

I also found [Bolt CMS](https://bolt.cm/) and their github thread about [multilingual support](https://github.com/bolt/bolt/issues/234) which points to an extension that looks also feasable providing multi-language support.

Hope that helps.

---

Update 09/2016:

We used ProcessWire to develop one of our sites and it is fantastic. The concept of combining Fields with Templates (in DB and as PHP file) gives enormous flexibility. And the multilingual part gets extremely easy. You just change the field with type `Text` to `TextLanguage`, specify the languages you want to use under >Setup >Languages, and they appear above the textfield and can be switched:

[image: multilingual CMS]

From my recent experience I can say that this is the best implementation of a multilingual CMS.

Answer (score 5):

I've looked for a PHP based CMS which supports multilingual text content, but I couldn't find solution that meets my needs.

From my experience I suggest to use [Django CMS](http://django-cms.org) it is very easy if you know [Django](http://djangoproject.com) basics and it supports mulitlanguage content nicely.

Comment: Cannot agree more, it's one of the best CMS I've ever seen!

Comment: Just for everyone who considers using this CMS: "django CMS requires Django 1.8, and Python 2.7, 3.3 or 3.4."

Answer (score 4):

I suggest **SilverStripe CMS**

http://www.silverstripe.org

And for the support of different domains take a look at the **Subsites Module** for SSCMS 
http://doc.silverstripe.org/modules:subsites

The SSCMS is based on Sapphire Framework, it is very easy to extend and customize the functionality.

Answer (score 2):

[FrogCMS](http://www.madebyfrog.com) is described as the PHP version of Radiant. I didn't use it myself but it looks pretty simple. The drawback is that its development seems to be stalled.

From my experience I'd recommend you to try out [Silverstripe](http://www.silverstripe.org/).

Comment: I actually found and had a look at Frog. But it was very buggy, at least on my server setup.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for three times **[award-winning](http://www.joomla.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=4122&Itemid=74)**, the **[Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/)**.

> Joomla is an award-winning content
>   management system (CMS), which enables
>   you to build Web sites and powerful
>   online applications. Many aspects,
>   including its ease-of-use and
>   extensibility, have made Joomla the
>   most popular Web site software
>   available. Best of all, Joomla is an
>   open source solution that is freely
>   available to everyone.

Comment: I would probably go for Drupal if the site was more complex. But both Drupal and Joomla are way to big for what I actually need. And I don't want my clients to have that many options in their admin.

Comment: In Joomla (and probably Drupal but I don't know it), it's possible to tailor the admin for each user needs. In Joomla you can also give access only to the frontend. That's a lot simpler (create and edit articles, mostly that).

Answer (score 1):

In my experience: Wordpress + [wpml](http://wpml.org)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a prepackaged CMS but Globalize http://github.com/joshmh/globalize2 gives you great power and flexibility in internationalizing a Ruby on Rails application.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Ubiquo + ubiquo_i18n plugin

http://guides.ubiquo.me/edge/ubiquo_i18n.html

The CMS interface easily allows what you are trying to accomplish: you can have one article translated into other languages, or simply maintain different articles per language.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers :)

Comment: Make sure you also answer questions that don't promote your product :)